# Output input selection as text to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, output

I'm a UI Designer working on a multi-page Q&A form, I'm a beginner with jQuery mostly mashing snippets together.

Here's the code: http://codepen.io/covanant/pen/GJZYLq

This part of the form is basically multiple accordions wrapped into tabs, I have most of it working as required but one of the things I need to do, is that whenever I a choice or option, I want to be able to output that option to an element as text right underneath the question.

The element is:

```
<span class="selected-answer"></span>
```

You can see it displayed in the first question in the demo, the way that I'd like it to work is that whenever I click the **Close All** button, it will fadeIn the .selected-answer element and when I click **Open All**, it will fadeOut the .selected-answer element.

The buttons:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default openall">Open All</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default closeall">Close All</a>
```

jQuery:

```
// Open All & Close All buttons
$('.closeall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse.in')
    .collapse('hide');
});
$('.openall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse:not(".in")')
    .collapse('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it doesn't make sense to give each of your select options the same value attribute. By convention, these should be distinct.  If you aren't using the value attribute, you can remove it altogether.  Otherwise, you should change it to something like:

```
<select>
    <option value="None Selected">None Selected</option>
    <option value="Photocell On">Photocell On</option>
    <option value="Off Control Only">Off Control Only</option>
    <option value="Photocell On / Off Control Only">Photocell On / Off Control Only</option>
</select>
```

Once that is sorted out, you need to go up the DOM hierarchy and find the right `span` element to change.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var span = $(this).closest('div.panel').find('span.selected-answer');
  span.text($(this).val());
});
```

For the checkbox questions, you I would do something like this:
HTML:

```
<span class="selected-answer">
    <ul class="checked-options">
        <li data-check="checkbox1">nWifi (nLight)</li>
        <li data-check="checkbox2">nLightFixtures</li>
        <li data-check="checkbox3">xCella (LC&D)</li>
        <li data-check="checkbox4">Daylight Harvesting</li>
        <li data-check="checkbox5">xPoint (LC&D)</li>
        <li data-check="checkbox6">nWifi (nLight)</li>                         
    </ul>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.checked-options li {
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  var checkbox = $(this);
  var id = checkbox.attr('id');

  if ($(this).prop('checked'))
    $('li[data-check="' + id + '"]').show();
  else
    $('li[data-check="' + id + '"]').hide();
});
```

As for the fading, this should do the trick:

```
// Open All & Close All buttons
$('.closeall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse.in')
    .collapse('hide');
  $('.selected-answer').fadeIn();// <-- Fade in
});
$('.openall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse:not(".in")')
    .collapse('show');
  $('.selected-answer').fadeOut();// <-- Fade out
});
```

Also, depending on whether you want all the questions open or closed by default when the form first loads, you may need to hide all the `.selected-answer` elements on page load.

Here's the updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPGLjd).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with VCode on using distinct values for each `option` in the `select` elements.  But instead of using the value you provide for each option, I think you should use the actual label, that way you can have a more description label, than the option value.

I modified a few of your existing functions to actually populate the selected answer.  First I noticed that you already have a function for handling changes to your select - in there I added a small snippet to get the selected answer and pass it to `nextQuestion`.

```
$(".panel-body select").change(function() {
  var selectElem = $(this);
  var answer = selectElem.find("option:selected").text();
  nextQuestion(selectElem, answer);
});
```

Then you also have input elements.  Here is your modified input change function:

```
$(".panel-body input").change(function() {
  var inputElem = $(this);
  var inputType = inputElem.attr('type');
  // common parent for input
  var commonParent = inputElem.closest(".panel-body");
  var answers = commonParent
    .find("input:checked")
    .closest("."+inputType)
    .find("label")
    .map(function(){return this.innerText;})
    .get()
    .join(", ");
  nextQuestion(inputElem, answers);
});
```

And now as you may have noticed, I added a parameter to the nextQuestion function. I put this code in nextQuestion because you were already accessing the parent there so I wanted to re-use that logic to populate the selected answer.

```
function nextQuestion(currentQuestion,selectedAnswer) {
  var parentEle = currentQuestion.parents(".panel");
  if (arguments.length>1) {
    parentEle.find('.selected-answer').text(selectedAnswer);
  }
  if (parentEle.next()) {
    parentEle.find(".fa-question").addClass("fa-check check-mark").removeClass("question-mark fa-question").text("");
  }
}
```

Just like VCode mentioned, you can do the fading of the answers using fadeIn/fadeOut

```
// Open All & Close All buttons
$('.closeall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse.in')
    .collapse('hide');
  $('.selected-answer').fadeIn();// <-- Fade in
});
$('.openall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse:not(".in")')
    .collapse('show');
  $('.selected-answer').fadeOut();// <-- Fade out
});
// hide all .selected-answers
$('.selected-answer').hide();
```

Here is a link to your codepen with my modifications: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGpXXK

Comment: It works except for the radio buttons, any idea why?

Comment: I didn't realize that the parent of the radio inputs was using a `.radio` class.  I updated my answer and the codepen to work with the radios too